# How to check jar successfully started when deploying with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to deploy and run the jar file to target server.
And I'm trying to trigger this job when scm being pushed.

I have to make sure that the deployed APP has no runtime error when starting.

My jenkins job execs 'xxx.jar start' in target server with SSH publisher.

How can I check that the jar file has been successfully started up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no answers to this question..
I solved this problem by other way.

I make my jenkins job to wait about 60 secs after starting the jar, then check apache access log whether its wwwcheck returns code 200 or not.(since my app is spring boot app)

I think there would be much better way. If anybody knows another solution, please let me know:)